# How to fix 'invalid character in identifier' when calling a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I made a function that can calculate the mass of a planet in python.

```
from math import pi
from scipy.constants import gravitational_constant as g


def planet_mass(dist, t):
    vel = (2 * pi * dist) / t
    return (vel**2) * dist / g
```

But calling the function with some specific parameters gives an error.

```
>>> planet_mass(‎149597870700,365.25*24*60*60)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    planet_mass(‎149597870700,365.25*24*60*60)
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

However, calling the function with other parameters like (10000,100000) seems to work fine.

```
>>> planet_mass(10000,100000)
59151849549836.72
```

I am using Sublime text 3 and SublimeREPL to run python. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cut & paste your code with a less forgiving editor, and you'll see the superfluous character in your call:

```
planet_mass(<200e>149597870700,365.25*24*60*60)
```

This is a non-printing character in many rendering paradigms, but shows up clearly in `vi`.  Just delete that character and you'll be fine.

Comment: Any editor that doesn't convert or ignore strange characters will do.  As I said in my answer, I used `vi`.